# Meaning of a code segment in R

Tags: r

I was debugging a code I found online, in order to debug it.  One of the line is:

```
z = train[train[,11]==i, 1:10]
```

where `train` is defined as:

```
train = matrix(0,nrow(y)/2,ncol(y))
```

and `y` is the input data from a .csv file (in the matrix form).  The code is for training a classifier from the input data given in the .csv form.  The file contains only `0`s and `1`s.

Wouldn't `train[,11]==i` return a Boolean value?  How is the `train` matrix being accessed by a Boolean parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets break it down:

```
# Create some data and a value to look for
> train <- matrix(1:121,11)
> i = 112

# This is a vector of column 11 of the matrix
> train[,11]
[1] 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121

# This is a vector of the same length as column 11 of the
# matrix with TRUE/FALSE depending on if the value equals i
> train[,11]==i
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

# Finally, this is then selecting the rows that had a TRUE
# value. So if the 2nd item in the column above is 112 (it is)
# then only the second value in the vector will be TRUE, so it
# will select the second row (could be more rows with different
# data in the matrix of course). It also selects only the first
# ten columns of that row, i.e. 1:10.
> train[train[,11]==i, 1:10]
[1]   2  13  24  35  46  57  68  79  90 101
```

Basically, you can use a boolean vector to select. It will also wrap as you would expect, so this next example will use TRUE then FALSE, then TRUE then FALSE, until the length 10 is reached.

```
x <- 1:10
x[c(T,F)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I come from a C++ background.  So, unlike what is done in C++, here `train[,11]==i` isn't used to access an array element, right?  Similarly, `1:10` isn't a parameter either.  Am I right?

Comment: Remember, it's not an array, it's a vector. So all your operations are vector based! In C++ `1:10 == 5` would be (syntax aside) be comparing an array with an int. In R, they are both vectors and it will use a vector operation checking each value if it is 5 and outputting a length 10 list of TRUE and FALSE.  Same goes for select.

Comment: A good way of thinking about this which actually just occurred to me is to think about the selection criteria being the part which is being processed into the output using the variable. so `x[1:3]` gets the first 3 elements of x. Booleans are a bit different as they get wrapped like in the example above. You can also do this: `x[c(1,1,2,2)]` which is basically saying. Give me 1 from x, 1 from x, 2 from x and 2 from x. Seems nuts at first (and oftentimes even after a long time), but there is a tiny nugget of sense in there.